# Import with Sql Workbench/J in Virtuoso a csv file with empty numeric fields

Tags: csv, virtuoso, sql-workbench-j

Using Sql Workbench/J I want to load a csv file into a Virtuoso table. I get a `NullPointerException` when in the file a numeric field is empty. 
The target table has a nullable column for the empty fields. The error is the following.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoPreparedStatement.setObject(VirtuosoPreparedStatement.java:846)
        at virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoPreparedStatement.setObject(VirtuosoPreparedStatement.java:789)
        at virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoPreparedStatement.setObject(VirtuosoPreparedStatement.java:773)
        at workbench.db.compare.BatchedStatement.setObject(BatchedStatement.java:120)
        at workbench.db.importer.DataImporter.processRowData(DataImporter.java:1368)
        at workbench.db.importer.DataImporter.insertRow(DataImporter.java:1297)
        at workbench.db.importer.DataImporter.processRow(DataImporter.java:1054)
        at workbench.db.importer.TextFileParser.processOneFile(TextFileParser.java:743)
        at workbench.db.importer.AbstractImportFileParser.start(AbstractImportFileParser.java:390)
        at workbench.db.importer.DataImporter.startImport(DataImporter.java:761)
        at workbench.sql.wbcommands.WbImport.execute(WbImport.java:827)
        at workbench.sql.StatementRunner.runStatement(StatementRunner.java:582)
        at workbench.sql.BatchRunner.executeScript(BatchRunner.java:877)
        at workbench.sql.BatchRunner.executeScript(BatchRunner.java:784)
        at workbench.sql.BatchRunner.runFiles(BatchRunner.java:642)
        at workbench.sql.BatchRunner.execute(BatchRunner.java:596)
        at workbench.WbManager.runBatch(WbManager.java:1075)
        at workbench.WbManager.startApplication(WbManager.java:929)
        at workbench.WbManager.main(WbManager.java:1227)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at workbench.WbStarter.main(WbStarter.java:143)
Importing file 'C:\dev\csvFiles\CLASSIFICATION_CODE.csv' into table CLASSIFICATION_CODE
The file "C:\dev\csvFiles\CLASSIFICATION_CODE.csv" was not imported
```

My table has the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE CLASSIFICATION_CODE 
(
  CLASSIFICATION_CODE_ID NUMERIC NOT NULL ,
  CLASSIFICATION_CATEGORY VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
  CLASSIFICATION_PRIORITY NUMERIC 
  CONSTRAINT PK_CLASS_CODE PRIMARY KEY (CLASSIFICATION_CODE_ID)   
);
```

The file I am trying to upload has the following content (the last field is empty).

```
CLASSIFICATION_CODE_ID,CLASSIFICATION_CATEGORY,CLASSIFICATION_PRIORITY
1,^3^,
2,^2^,
3,^2^,
4,^2^,
5,^2^,
6,^3^,
```

Finally this is the `WbImport` command I use to import it.

```
WbImport -type=text
-file='C:\dev\csvFiles\CLASSIFICATION_CODE.csv'
-delimiter=,
-table=DB.PEST.CLASSIFICATION_CODE
-quoteChar=^
-badfile='C:\dev\csvFiles\rejected'
-emptyStringIsNull=false;
```

I do not see any parameter to tell to Sql Workbench/J that the field for the column `CLASSIFICATION_PRIORITY`can be null. Am I missing something?

I am using

- Virtuoso Open Source Edition Version 7.2.4.3217-threads as of Apr 25 2016 Compiled for Win64 (x86_64-generic-win-64)
- the patched Virtuoso JDBC driver `virtjdbc4_2.jar` for  jdk1.8 located to [this link](http://id.myopenlink.net/DAV/home/smalinin/Public/JDBC/).

Comment: You've provided no version information, so I'm wondering whether all components are up to date? I'd check Java, the JDBC Driver for Virtuoso, and SQL Workbench/J; possibly also worth checking Virtuoso itself, thought it's not implicated in the reported error.

Comment: @TallTed I've added the reference to the JDBC driver. Actually I have used the one patched by Sergey 4 weeks ago. Maybe now it is available as well in the repository, I am not sure.

Comment: OK, so Virtuoso is latest stable VOS Release for Windows, and I gather you're using Java 8 (presumably the latest and greatest).  What about *SQL Workbench/J*, which *may* be the culprit here?  Last, I guess you worked directly with Sergey to get that pre-release JDBC driver.  It's probably worth doing the same about this issue!

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by a bug in the driver [`virtjdbc4_2.jar`](http://id.myopenlink.net/DAV/home/smalinin/Public/JDBC/)
The current version of the driver at the same link fixes the problem.

The driver can be found in the Virtuoso github repository as wel .